# How to enable auto-trimming spaces before punctuation on Android Keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I am trying to fix a problem related to Android Keyboard (AOSP).

**Case 1:** When any word is inputted from the keyboard suggestion strip and then any letter for the keyboard, a *space* is automatically placed after the first word.

**Case 2:** Again, if the *period* key is pressed after inputting the word from the suggestion strip, the space before the period is trimmed automatically.

It's the expected behavior as the keyboard treats period as punctuation.

But if any *period sign* from another language (i.e. *U+0964*) is pressed after inputting the word from the suggestion strip,  the space before the period is not being trimmed automatically. The keyboard is treating this period sign like a normal character, same as case 1.

So, how can I enable the feature to auto-trim space before period sign from other languages?

I want to do it on the [OpenBoard keyboard](https://github.com/openboard-team/openboard).

Comment: SO I helped write Swype 10 years ago.  We had an autospacing feature there.  We actually worked the opposite way-  rather than spacing after you wrote a word, we spaced when you started writing the next word. That result of that was that we didn't need to ever delete an extra space we inserted, we just had a set of (I think 12 or so) rules we followed when they started inputting the next word to decide whether to space or not.  It worked a lot better that way.  I'd consider reversing their current logic of post-spacing and moving to pre-spacing.

Comment: But for doing exactly what you ask-  if it deletes the space for a normal period, find the place where it does that.  See what function it uses to tell if its punctuation.  And replace it with a version of the function that also recognizes the character you want.

Answer (score 0):

Characters that should be treated as punctuation, can be defined in `donottranslate-config-spacing-and-punctuations.xml` file in the `values` directory.

For example for Bengali, the directory is `res/values-bn`
The XML file from the default `values` directory can be used as a template.

*app/src/main/res/values/donottranslate-config-spacing-and-punctuations.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <!-- TODO: these settings depend on the language. They should be put either in the dictionary
         header, or in the subtype maybe? -->
    <!-- Symbols that are suggested between words -->
    <string name="suggested_punctuations">!,?,\\,,:,;,\",(,),\',-,/,@,_</string>
    <!-- Symbols that are normally preceded by a space (used to add an auto-space before these) -->
    <string name="symbols_preceded_by_space">([{&amp;</string>
    <!-- Symbols that are normally followed by a space (used to add an auto-space after these) -->
    <string name="symbols_followed_by_space">.,;:!?)]}&amp;</string>
    <!-- Symbols that behave like a single punctuation when typed next to each other -->
    <string name="symbols_clustering_together"></string>
    <!-- Symbols that separate words -->
    <!-- Don't remove the enclosing double quotes, they protect whitespace (not just U+0020) -->
    <string name="symbols_word_separators">"&#x0009;&#x0020;&#x000A;&#x00A0;"()[]{}*&amp;&lt;&gt;+=|.,;:!?/_\"</string>
    <!-- Word connectors -->
    <string name="symbols_word_connectors">\'-</string>
    <!-- The sentence separator code point, for capitalization and auto-insertion -->
    <!-- U+002E: "." FULL STOP   ; 2Eh = 46d -->
    <integer name="sentence_separator">46</integer>
    <!-- The abbreviation marker code point -->
    <!-- U+002E: "." FULL STOP   ; 2Eh = 46d -->
    <integer name="abbreviation_marker">46</integer>
    <!-- Symbols that terminate sentences and require capitalization on the next char -->
    <string name="symbols_sentence_terminators">.?!</string>
    <!-- Whether this language uses spaces between words -->
    <bool name="current_language_has_spaces">true</bool>
</resources>
```